# How come this cherrypy application does not use `expose`decorators?

Tags: python, decorator, cherrypy, web-frameworks

I had previously learnd that in cherrypy you have to expose a method to make it a view target and this is also spread all over the documentation:

```
  import cherrypy
  @cherrypy.expose
  def index():
    return "hello world"
```

But I have inherited a cherrypy application which seems to work without exposing anything

How does this work? Was the exposing requirement removed from newer versions?

It is not easy googling for this, I found a lot about exposing and decorators on cherrypy, but nothing about "cherrypy without expose"

This is the main serve.py script, I removed some parts from it for brevity here:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import cherrypy
from root import RouteRoot


dispatcher = cherrypy.dispatch.RoutesDispatcher()
dispatcher.explicit = False
dispatcher.connect(u'system',      u'/system', RouteRoot().index)

conf = {
  '/' : {
    u'request.dispatch' : dispatcher,
    u'tools.staticdir.root' : conf_app_BASEDIR_ROOT, 
    u'log.screen' : True,
  },
  u'/my/pub' : {
    u'tools.staticdir.debug' : True,
    u'tools.staticdir.on' : True,
    u'tools.staticdir.dir' : u"pub",
  },
}
#conf = {'/' : {'request.dispatch' : dispatcher}}

cherrypy.tree.mount(None, u"/", config=conf)
import conf.ip_config as ip_config  
cherrypy.config.update({
  'server.socket_host': str(ip_config.host),
  'server.socket_port': int(ip_config.port),
})

cherrypy.quickstart(None, config=conf)
```

And there is no èxpose` anywhere in the application. How can it work?

File root.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from mako.template import Template

class RouteRoot:

  def index(self):
    return "Hello world!"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it relies on the routes dispatcher which works slightly differently. Mainly, it doesn't need the `exposed` attribute that the `expose` decorator sets because the URLs are explicitly described (as you can see with the `connect(...)` method). On the other hand, the default CherryPy dispatcher doesn't provide an explicit mapping between URLs and objects. When a request hits the application's engine, it must be go through the tree of applications you mounted initially. It uses the `exposed` attribute to determine if a method can take part in the URL mapping. This gives a chance to the developer to write methods in a controller class that can't be accessed by a URL mapping process.

Answer (score 0):

I have read this page: http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/concepts/dispatching.html

I am not sure but maybe the dispatching replaces the necessity for exposing.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the app doesn't uses the default dispatcher. It is explained (in bold!) in cherrypy's doc upon dispatchers